# Python - Django Select From Table Where Value "IN" - Error invalid literal for int() with base 10: ','

Tags: python, mysql, django

How do I select `MySQL` value `IN` in Python/Django?

I have a HTML form (input field) where I submit values separated by commas. `1,2,3`. These values are an `Integer` datatypes in my DB Table.

My Python code:

```
n = request.POST['gcn']
results = MyTable.objects.filter(gcn__in=[n])
```

When I submit just one number without comma, I do get the correct results, once I add comma or submit multiple values `1,2` I get an error

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: ','
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
n = request.POST['gcn']
n = n.replace(' ', '').split(',')
results = MyTable.objects.filter(gcn__in=n)
```

Comment: Wow! This must be fastest correct response I ever got on SO! Thanks again for your help and your time! I will accept the answer once the system will allow me to!

Comment: We are to help us each other.

Answer (score 1):

You are tring to search in `['1,2,3']`.

```
gcn = request.POST.get('gcn', '')
gcn = gcn.split(',')
results = MyTable.objects.filter(gcn__in=gnc)
```

This will create a proper `gnc` list: `['1', '2', '3']`.

Comment: Thank you for showing me another way how to correctly create proper list!